# iPad or iOS: PDF reader app that can display references when clicking on the corresponding citations

Tags: pdf, ios, pdf-viewer, ipad

I am looking for an iPad app for reading research papers. This app should be able to display (using tooltip for example) the corresponding reference when the user clicks on a citation).

On macOS, I have been using [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) (when hovering the mouse over a citation, its reference is displayed as a tooltip). Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an alternative for iPad.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!